# query to C# in mongodb 3.2

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following query:

```
db.products.find({name: "4-Year Protection Plan - Geek Squad"}, {name: 1, sku: 1}).limit(10)
```

How can I translate it to C#?

Comment: ok - found the answer: 

var fields = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name").Include("sku"); 

var c = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Project(fields).Limit(10);

Answer (score 1):

ok - found the answer:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", "4-Year Protection Plan - Geek Squad");
var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("name");
var fields = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name").Include("sku");

var c = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Project(fields).Limit(10).Count();
```